# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so

Tags: java, missing-data, kali-linux

Just wanna load a .jar file but I can't, and when running `java --version` I get:

`openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19`,

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4+8-Debian-1)`, and

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4+8-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
    at MarieSim1.main(MarieSim1.java:15)
```

I'm running Kali Linux and I'm pretty new to this, so any help with downloading necessary libraries would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 31):

The cause of this error may be that only "headless" part of JDK is installed, which does not include GUI libraries. Try to do `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`, this should add necessary parts if they are missing.

Comment: This is the exact cause. I did this action, and no other, and it 100% fixed it.

Comment: For any fedora users: `sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt reinstall openjdk-17-jre
```

This solved mine, you can also try

```
sudo apt reinstall openjdk-17-jdk
```

Comment: your answers duplicates the other answer and doesn't add anything new